# How to speed up Elasticsearch reindex operation?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can we speed up elasticsearch (v 5.3) reindex operation by setting replicas to zero and increasing the refresh interval or is it already taken care internally?

Comment: I would think that the replication will happen after the main shards are ready so while it will be slower to finish with replicas the index will be available at the same time as it would have been with no replicas. On the other hand this is probably easy to confirm via experimentation

Comment: @apokryfos You are talking about master-slave architecture. Master-slave is available only in Lucene(lucene-replication) and Solr. In case of ElasticSearch we have distributed indexation with the following schema https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-top-down#primary-concerns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to [improve indexing speed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/tune-for-indexing-speed.html) you can use the following:

- Use bulk requests
- Use multiple workers/threads to send data to Elasticsearch
- **Increase the refresh interval**
- **Disable refresh and replicas for initial loads**
- Use auto-generated ids
- Increase indexing buffer size

Related to you question - ElasticSearch is designed for continuous log processing that's why all these actions are not automatic. In case of bulk reindexings you have to change all these settings manually and restore them at the end:

- refresh interval for Lucene index writer
- replication factor for distributed processor
- index buffer size for merge scheduler